# how to debug pytorch lightening import issue

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

does anyone know why i'm getting this error?

trying to:
`import lightning.pytorch as pl`

getting:
`OSError: libtorch_hip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

```
pytorch-forecasting==1.0.0
pytorch-lightning==2.0.5
torch==2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I am running the same versions you indicated on Ubuntu 18.04 and have successfully used your import command. Can you try the following import instead (It is the suggested 'import' way in the pip installation of pytorch-lightning https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-lightning/?

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
```

Another suggestion would be to check that the Pytorch library is the CUDA Pytorch version. Indeed, this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo/issues/3200) is similar to yours, and, in their case, to solve the issue, they installed a Torchaudio CUDA version. It could be that, in your case, you need to install the CUDA version of Pytorch